# Merging 2 arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

```
first_arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
second_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

And I'd like to unite them to an array or a list like this:

```
third_arr = [['A',1], ['B',2], ['C',3], ['D',4], ['E',5], ['F',6]]
or my_list = [['A',1], ['B',2], ['C',3], ['D',4], ['E',5], ['F',6]]
```

What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Use the `zip()` function => https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip

Comment: There are slightly confusing references to array versus list here, but I suspect that you want `list(map(list, zip(first_arr, second_arr)))`

Comment: Just to note: you have *lists*, not arrays. Also, whatever use you have in mind likely will not care about the distinction between `[['A',1] , ...]` and `[('A', 1), ...]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip()` to merge the arrays...

```
first_arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
second_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

third_arr = list(zip(first_arr, second_arr))

print(third_arr)
```

Which results in...

```
[('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('D', 4), ('E', 5), ('F', 6)]
```

There is no difference between `('A',1)` and `['A',1]` in most cases. However, if you want to, you can change then from tuples to lists by assigning `third_arr` to the following...

```
...

third_arr = [list(t) for t in zip(first_arr, second_arr)]

print(third_arr)
```

Which results in...

```
[['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3], ['D', 4], ['E', 5], ['F', 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the two lists, you can create a third list joining the elements of the two lists using the method `.append()` in a `for` loop:

```
first_arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
second_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

my_list = []

for i in range(0,len(first_arr)):
    my_list.append([first_arr[i],second_arr[i]])

my_list

[['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3], ['D', 4], ['E', 5], ['F', 6]]
```